# CLR Sproc Permissions

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, clrstoredprocedure

When I'm trying to execute a clr sproc (Still in C# IDE for this) I have permission errors. The error is " Request for the permission of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission,... failed", I've looked around online and it seems to throw back to IIS settings (I'm not using IIS nor am I using a website so these solutions don't apply to me), now I tried two separate connection strings for this as well (context connection = true, as well the way I usually do it which is the huge long one that says it's a trusted connection and the database name) but both return the same permissions failed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you sure your SQL server user has the correct permissions?  Usually when I've gotten this in the past, it's because the user (using a specified UName & PWord) or my AD User had not been set up on the SQL Server instance (or DB) I was trying to access.

Comment: Yes because another application that makes calls to and from the same instance of the database (Separate VS instance because the one program is a form designed and the one in question is a CLR Sproc make attempt) doesn't have any issues

Comment: So I found a different tutorial and redid everything according to the tutorial ( http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CLR_Stored_Procedure.aspx ) which worked however the tutorial from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5czye81z(VS.80).aspx didn't work (It gave the security) so I don't know what happened.  I'd like to find out though, so I'll leave this open and hopefully someone can clear it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is CLR enabled within your instance of SQL server?

You can enable it by running the following SQL statement against your SQL server:

sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
GO

Once this is ran, the assembly needs to be registered to SQL:

CREATE ASSEMBLY 
ASSEMBLYNAME
FROM 'Full path to assembly' --e.g. C:\sproc.dll
WITH Permission_SET = SAFE
GO

Create the stored procedure like this (if you haven't already)
CREATE PROC clrsp_InsertEmployee 
(
 Comma delimited parameters   ) --Parameters example @City VARCHAR(25), @state VARCHAR(2)
AS EXTERNAL NAME AssemblyName.StoredProcedures.Function
Go

Let me know if this helps. Other than that, you may need to setup permissions to the tables based on the user that you are utilizing to access SQL.

Comment: Well I did the first assembly statement and it said there was already a stored procedure was identical to an already registered name so I found that (My mistake for not seeing it sooner) and when I try to run it it gives me the security error still.  Since it's already showing, I shouldn't need to do the create, right?

Thanks for your help and anymore you can provide

Answer (score 0):

Speak with your DBA regarding your users database permissions. This is probably not an issue in code.

Comment: It's a local database on my machine.  Copied from the development environment for the specific purposes of testing.  I have another program that can properly do SQL commands to and from it, locally as well.

Comment: @CSharpProgrammer: Can that other program successfully execute the stored procedure you're trying to?

Comment: No because I'm making it as a CLR Sproc, and as far as I know, I can't make it unless it properly goes through the build

Comment: @CSharpProgrammer: Have you stepped into the code and made sure in the actual connection object the credentials in use are the same as when you run stuff in management studio? Also there are special permissions specifically for running CLR Sprocs which your user may not have.

Comment: The credentials are the same between my program that can connect to the database without issue but I will double check on the management studio side.  Likewise, I will have to look into the permissions for running CLR Sprocs if that is the case,  I have enabled them but I don't know about the permissions part.

Thanks for the help, I'll have to take a look at these issues Monday morning